# How to compute the Surface Dice-Sørensen Coefficient in pytorch?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I would like to compute the *Surface Dice-Sørensen Coefficient* from this  [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.04430.pdf) (page 19)in python3/pytorch.

I have to point out, that I do **not** try to implement the simple *standard volumetric Dice-Sørensen Coefficient*! This one would look as follows in my implementation:

```py
import torch

def volumetric_DSC(M1, M2):
    M1 = M1.view(-1)
    M2 = M2.view(-1)
    dividend = 2 * (M1 * M2).sum()
    divisor = (M1 * M1).sum() + (M2 * M2).sum()
    return dividend / divisor

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m1 = torch.empty(5, 5, 5).uniform_(0, 1)
    m1 = torch.bernoulli(m1)
    m2 = torch.empty(5, 5, 5).uniform_(0, 1)
    m2 = torch.bernoulli(m2)
    loss = volumetric_DSC(m1, m2)
    print("loss = {0}".format(loss))
```

How can I extend this code to a Surface Dice-Sørensen Coefficient loss?

Answer (score 2):

A surface dice implementation was provided [here](https://github.com/deepmind/surface-distance) as part of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.04430.pdf) study. You can use it as an evaluation metric but not as a loss function as it contains non-differentiable ops. You will need to provide a "tolerance" distance i.e. a surface dice of 0.9 means that 90% of surfaces lie within the tolerance (which is better calculated from the data itself, such as the inter-observer variation of the task you are solving)